# Vue.js / Nuxt App that serves up django pages

Tags: django, vue.js, nuxt.js

This is more of a general but very specific question as it pertains to a large, preexisting ecommerce site so I'll do my best to be as specific and succinct as possible...

I have a monolithic Django App that currently uses Django Templates as its frontend layer. Everything has been fine tuned down to the last pixel to extract as much SEO value out of the current setup.

The company now wants to move to a Vue.js FE, however they want to do this process piecemeal, and NOT do the whole SPA in one go.

This brings up the following challenge:

I understand that with these new vue/react libraries, when seo web crawlers crawl the page, the js code needs to be "pre-rendered" in order to see what's actually on the page. And because we are revamping a lot of widgets that have to do with products, their names, their prices, etc. i fear that we are going to lose some very relevant data that have to do with keeping our SEO score high.

That being said, I'm wondering if it's at all possible to create a Nuxt app, and then wrap *some* of the django template pages inside of this nuxt app, while other parts are written in vue.

For example, the product-list-page would be written as a collection of Vue components, but the about page, would render the /about/ view from the django app, and output the resulting HTML inside of a  (just thinking out loud here.)

This way i can server side render the entire app, without literally rewriting each page into a Vue component.

Is anything like this remotely possible? Or is there a better alternative?